# Deadlock with ReadUncommitted?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

In ADO.NET, does setting the transactions isolation level to ReadUncommitted and then rolling back that transaction work effectively as a "dirty read"?

If so, why does it get deadlocked on ExecuteReader?

Code:

```
 command.Transaction = connection.CreateTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
 command.CommandTimeout = 0;
 command.CommandText = query;
 command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
 ...
```

Comment: Dirty read doesn't mean that it doesn't do any locks, so it is possible to have deadlocks still with dirty reads.

Answer (score 0):

Read Uncommitted will allow the transaction to read inserts/updates made by other transactions that have not yet committed, essentially functioning as a dirty read.